# Excel like formulas with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with this format

```
User_id|2014-01|2014-02|2014-03|2014-04|2014-05|...|2014-12
1      |   7   | NaN   | NaN   | NaN   | NaN   |...|  NaN
2      | NaN   |   5   | NaN   | NaN   |   9   |...|  NaN
3      |   2   |   4   | NaN   | NaN   | NaN   |...|  NaN
```

In words, the columns are months, the index is the `user_id` and each cell contains an integer number, or `NaN`

The numbers represents actions that were taken, and an action is considered successful if `3` months after it, no other action was needed.

*My goal is to find the list of successful actions*

In Excel, I'd write a formula like this:

```
Sheet2!E5=AND(Sheet1!E5<>"NaN",Sheet1!D5="NaN",Sheet1!C5="NaN",Sheet1!B5="NaN")
```

And would drag it to the rest of the columns, and then I would have an indicator whether an action was successful.

How can this be done efficiently with pandas ?

**Sample output:**

For the example given above, the desired output should be:

```
User_id|2014-01|2014-02|2014-03|2014-04|2014-05|
1      |   T   |   F   |   F   |   F   |   F   |
2      |   F   |   F   |   F   |   F   |   ?   |
3      |   F   |   T   |   F   |   F   |   F   |
```

Comment: So what are you after? Whether for a given month it is `NaN` and the 3 previous months are also `NaN`?

Comment: You need to show more example data and also add desired results.  Based on your description, that excel formula would not be sufficient because the action month can vary from row to row.  Just replicating that excel formula is very easy in pandas with `any()` or `all()`.

Comment: I'm interested in an indicator for `int` values with 3 consequent `NaN`s after them, I've added an example.

Comment: Ah, thanks, sample output helps a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to deal with right-most columns (you just have a '?') but you can adjust fairly easily starting from the following code or just pad out data with placeholder numbers or NaNs:

```
df2 = df.copy()    
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)):
    df2.iloc[:,i] = ((df.iloc[:,i].notnull()) & 
                     (df.iloc[:,i+1:i+4].apply(lambda x: all(x.isnull()),axis=1)))
```

Starting data `df`:

```
   User_id  2014-01  2014-02  2014-03  2014-04  2014-05
0        1        7      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1        2      NaN        5      NaN      NaN        9
2        3        2        4      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Results `df2`:

```
   User_id 2014-01 2014-02 2014-03 2014-04 2014-05
0        1    True   False   False   False   False
1        2   False   False   False   False   False
2        3   False    True   False   False   False
```

For the aforementioned padding, you could add three placeholder columns and then tweak the remaining code slightly:

```
df[['pad1','pad2','pad3']] = np.nan

df2 = df.copy().iloc[:,:-3]    
for i in range(1,len(df2.columns)):
    df2.iloc[:,i] = ((df.iloc[:,i].notnull()) & 
                     (df.iloc[:,i+1:i+4].apply(lambda x: all(x.isnull()),axis=1)))
```

And now you have one 'True' in the last column:

```
   User_id 2014-01 2014-02 2014-03 2014-04 2014-05
0        1    True   False   False   False   False
1        2   False   False   False   False    True
2        3   False    True   False   False   False
```